# Ruta register me redirige a Home laravel 7

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

Estoy utilizando el sistema de LOGIN por defecto de laravel 7, aqui viene mi problema:

Ruta register:
localhost:8000/register

Ruta home
localhost:8000/home

Cuando esto logeado e ingreso manualmente a la ruta register (registrar usuario) me redirige automaticamente a HOME, solo me permite ver el formulario de registeo de usuafio cuando no estoy logeado.

Porque pasa eso ?
Como puedo evitarlo?

Comment: Quiero que esa persona que ya esta logeada, pueda registrar a otros usuarios.

Comment: Javier entonces por favor edita y agrega ese detalle a tu pregunta para que sea mas clara

Comment: @BetaM por lo que entiendo, esta usando el Auth por defecto de Laravel

Comment: Alli dice que uso el Auth de Laravel.